# change row color in sonata admin bundle dependent on a value of a field

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata

I have the sonata admin bundle and can't figure out, how to change a styling dependent on a field value in a form template.

for example field difficulty ... the higher the difficulty value is, the more red colored the record row should be ...

How can i do this? I spend hours to understand the twig templates in sonata, but the more i read this templates, the more i get confused.

There are block calls amongst a template and its not possible to figure out, where this calls leading to or come from.

I use symfony 2 with Sonata Admin Bundle.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your own template wich extends SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig and either override the `$templates` property of your admin class or pass it in your admin service declaration like so:

```
librinfo_crm.admin.organism:
        class: Librinfo\CRMBundle\Admin\OrganismAdmin
        arguments: [~, Librinfo\CRMBundle\Entity\Organism, LibrinfoCRMBundle:OrganismAdmin]
        tags:
            -   name: sonata.admin
                manager_type: orm
                group: Customers Relationship Management
                label: librinfo.crm.organism_admin.label
                label_translator_strategy: blast_core.label.strategy.librinfo
        calls:
            - [ setTemplate, [edit, LibrinfoCRMBundle:OrganismAdmin:edit.html.twig]] #set a custom edit template
            - [ setTemplate, [show, LibrinfoCRMBundle:OrganismAdmin:show.html.twig]] #sets a custom show template
```

your custom template will need to override the default sonata template for example:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% block form %}
    {# your custom code #}
{% endblock %}
```

If you don't know wich block or wich template to extend tell me wich view you want to customize (list, edit, show) but probably all of them.

Then to retrieve the field that you want or anything you can use the

`{% dump %}`

to dump all variables of the template in the profiler or

`{% dump(myVar) %}` to dump a specific variable

**EDIT**

`base_template` is a variable passed from the controller that contains the name of the template.

> If you look closely, all of these templates ultimately extend the
>   base_template variable that’s passed from the controller. This
>   variable will always take the value of one of the above mentioned
>   global templates, and this is how changes made to those files affect
>   all the SonataAdminBundle interface.

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html#crudcontroller-actions-templates

If you dump the `base_template` variable you'll know which template is extended.

For the `parentForm` block just look above:

`{% use 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit_form.html.twig' with form as parentForm %}`

This line imports SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit_form.html.twig `form` block aliased as `parentForm`.

So `{{ block('parentForm') }}` is a call to render a `form` block from SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit_form.html.twig.

Comment: A perfect example i don't understand ... 
the base_edit extends base_template ... where is the base_template template? in block_form only a 'parent_form' is called and its not possible to find the template even with a full text search ...

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a bit forward!