# Change field depending of other in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony3.x

In a Symfony3 project, i have a SonataAdminBundle form like this :

```
  protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {

        $formMapper->add('rentalTime', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Durée de location',
            'multiple' => false,
            'choices' => array(
                '3H' => '3',
                '24H' => '24',
            )
        ));
        $formMapper->add('rentalTimeType', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Type de durée de location',
            'multiple' => false,
            'choices' => array(
                'Heure(s)' => 'H',
                'Plage de jours' => 'R'
            )
        ));
    .
    .
    .
```

When i change the value of rentalTime i want to change the value of rentaltimeType.
Example: If i select 24H in rentalTime field and automatically the rentalTimeType change for 'Plage de jours'.

I've read a lot of topic with the use of $subject but it's not exactly what i need.

- [change row color in sonata admin bundle dependent on a value of a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898481/change-row-color-in-sonata-admin-bundle-dependent-on-a-value-of-a-field)
- [Correct way to use FormEvents to customise fields in SonataAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246192/correct-way-to-use-formevents-to-customise-fields-in-sonataadmin)
- [Sonata User Admin - Custom field dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526547/sonata-user-admin-custom-field-dependency)

So is it possible to do what i need ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ChoiceFieldMaskType Like said in this [documentation](https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/4.x/reference/form_types/#sonata-adminbundle-form-type-choicefieldmasktype)

> According the choice made only associated fields are displayed. The others fields are hidden.

You could the choose to display a field rentalTimeTypeHour or rentalTimeTypeDays depending on the choice value.

Answer (score -2):

You can customize the form specific to the data that was submitted by the user.

[Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms)

Comment: Yes i know but that is not in real time in client side. It's only when the form is submitted or reopened for edition.

Comment: there is an ajax submit, so the second field is relative to the select choice in the first side

Comment: Oh ok , i didn't see that. I'm gonna try this and I'll let you know. Thx